# BehaviorSubject initial value not working with share()

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-observables

`share()` operator is applied to a BehaviorSubject. 
BehaviorSubject has initial value.

Goal is to create a single shared subscribtion. **But this shared subscribtion does not seem to work when BehaviorSubject has an initial value.**

Getting unexpected results.

Code shown below:

```
let subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0);
let published = subject
                  .do(v => console.log("side effect"))
                  .share();

published.subscribe((v) => console.log(v+" sub1"));
published.subscribe((v) => console.log(v+" sub2"));

subject.next(1);
```

Result:

```
"side effect"
"0 sub1"
"side effect"
"1 sub1"
"1 sub2"
```

Expected Result:

```
"side effect"
"0 sub1"
"1 sub1"  <------------- this is missing from actual result
"side effect"
"1 sub1"
"1 sub2"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RxJS share() operator with BehaviorSubject and async pipe - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742855/rxjs-share-operator-with-behaviorsubject-and-async-pipe-angular)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand what's confusing here.

The `BehaviorSubject` emits only on subscription. However, you're using the `share()` operator which internally is just a shorthand for `publish()->refCount()`. When the first observer subscribes it triggers the `refCount()` and it makes the subscription to its source which causes the side-effect in `do()` and also prints the default value in the observer `0 sub1`:

```
"side effect"
"0 sub1"
```

Then you subscribe with another observer but this subscription is made only to the `Subject` class inside the `publish()` operator (that's what it's made for). So the second observer won't receive the default `0` nor trigger the side effect.

When you later call `subject.next(1)` it'll made the last three lines of output:

```
"side effect"
"1 sub1"
"1 sub2"
```

Comment: So how can we achieve "side effect", "0 sub1", "0 sub2" order for initial subscription and then "side effect","1 sub1", "1 sub2" after the first `next` call?