# RxJS: Share() an Observable & Emit Last Value to each new subscriber

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-services

I'm using .share() to share an Observable among all subscribers to a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ChannelsService {
    private store: IChannel[] = [];
    private _own: BehaviorSubject<IChannel[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    readonly own: Observable<IChannel[]> = this._own.asObservable().share();
    ...(the rest of the service basically makes CRUD http request and then calls this._own.next(result) to emit the result to all subscribers)
}
```

Problem:
Only the first subscription to the Observable (ChannelsService.own.subscribe(...)) is getting initial data, the rest of subscriptions get 'null' as a first subscription's value. Next calls to  this._own.next(result) will emit its values to all subscribers properly.

Any idea of how to .share() an Observable among multiple subscribers and get the last value emitted for all the subscribers? (I've tried .share().last() but no way...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want `shareReplay()` (since RxJS 5.4.0) or `publishReplay().refCount()` in RxJS < 5.4.0.

For example:

```
this._own.asObservable()
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount()
  .take(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the detailed link, it worked!

I would also recommend the reading of this article: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html#card_1501173301527_7527 
It helped me to understand the underlying question: the difference between cold and hot observables. It recommend publishLast().refCount() that, from what I've seen, works the same way: it shares the same and unique subscription between all the subscribers and emit the last value on subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Some small improvement:

```
@Injectable()
export class ChannelsService {
    private store: IChannel[] = [];
    private _own: BehaviorSubject<IChannel[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    get own(){
      this._own.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Now you can do the following in your components:

```
channels$: Observable<IChannel[]> = this.service.own;
```

And **dont forget** to unsubscribe from it if u manually subscribe to it

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Jota.Toledo. Maybe your option is more elegant, but this way I'm able to call this.channelsService.own from components too...

Comment: removing the share operator has no effect?

Answer (score 0):

Your results are the expected using share without initialization value. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825763/behaviorsubject-initial-value-not-working-with-share/42827023)

As commented before.. you have shortcuts to help you with this use case. Just a simple addition: giving "null" as initial value and filtering by those who are not.

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();

const behaviorWithoutShortcut = subject
  .multicast(new Rx.BehaviorSubject(null))
  .refCount()
  .filter(function (x) { return x !== null; });

const behaviorWithShortcut = subject
  .publishBehavior(null)
  .refCount()
  .filter(function (x) { return x !== null; });
```

I just made an example [jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/soxidazege/edit?html,js,console,output)