# RxJS share() operator with BehaviorSubject and async pipe - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a `BehaviorSubject` that is being consumed as an observable:

```
testForStack$: Observable<boolean>;

ngOnInit(){
    const bs = new BehaviorSubject(true);
    this.testForStack$ = bs
      .asObservable()
      .do(t => console.log('subscribed'))
      .share();
}
```

This observable is being piped through three `async` pipes in the template:

```
Sub1: {{testForStack$ | async}}<br>
Sub2: {{testForStack$ | async}}<br>
Sub3: {{testForStack$ | async}}
```

The issue is only the first (`Sub1`) is getting the value of true

```
Sub1: true
Sub2: 
Sub3:
```

If I remove the `.share()`, all three values get the value of true, but this causes the issue of multiple subscriptions.

Any thoughts on why using the BehaviorSubject causes this behavior? It's being used as an observable so I would assume the above code would work correctly.

This is similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40819423/4912604) as well.

Comment: What do you mean by the "issue of multiple subscriptions?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a correct behavior. The `share()` operator keeps only one subscription to its parent and `BehaviorSubject` emits its value only on subscription.

This means that when you use the first `{{testForStack$ | async}}` it subscribes at the end of the chain to `share()` which subscribes to its parents which results in subscribing to the source `BehaviorSubject` that emits its value immediately.

However, the second and all consecutive `{{testForStack$ | async}}` subscribe to `share()` which already has subscribed to its parent and won't make any more subscriptions so there's nothing to push the source value to these observers.

An easy solution could be using `shareReplay(1)` (depending on your RxJS version) you should probably use `publishReplay(1).refCount()` instead because of these issues (or its pipable equivalents):

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3336
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3127

Comment: ok awesome explanation. The publishReplay(1).refCount() works great, and the info on the BehaviorSubject makes sense

Comment: I would tend to say that the use of `share` with Subject is never required since Subjects are multicasted by definition. Any thought on this position?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the share operator. Instead do something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="testForStack$ | async as testForStack">

  Sub1: {{ testForStack }}
  Sub2: {{ testForStack }} 
  Sub3: {{ testForStack }}

</ng-container>
```

There are various other ways, for example you could use the same approach with a template using `ngTemplateOutlet` if you don't like use of the `*ngIf`. This approach allows you to create an alias variable in the same manner:

```
<ng-template
  let-testForStack 
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: testForStack$ | async }"
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="selfie" #selfie>

  Sub1: {{ testForStack }}
  Sub2: {{ testForStack }} 
  Sub3: {{ testForStack }}

</ng-template>
```

This `ng-template` code is self-referencing (which is valid) and wholly untested but "should" work and avoid the use of `*ngIf`

Read more here:

https://nitayneeman.com/posts/using-single-subscription-for-multiple-async-pipes-in-angular/

Answer (score 3):

Update for RxJS 7 / 2022:

I found this question because I started adding `share` to pipelines that began with a BehaviorSubject, but included expensive intermediate transforms that were running once for each subscriber.

The pattern I think is going to work for me is

```
const transformedValues$ = subj.pipe(
  map(expensiveTransform),
  shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: true})
);
```

This addresses the comment @martin made about needing to manually include `refCount`.  The transform shouldn't run at all if `$transformedValues` has no subscribers.  On the first subscription, the transform should run once; subsequent subscribers should get a replay from the `shareReplay` operator.